# Problem with Arduino driver! Port option not visible. How to resolve it?

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading

I am not able to upload sketch because my Windows 8.1 PC is not able to recognise it. It used to work fine but suddenly my driver disappeared from my device manager and no light is shown on the Arduino uno led also.

I tried to uninstall and install the Arduino IDE again but still didn't work.

Note:- whenever I connect the USB cable to my PC, I see a dim light glowing for few milli seconds.

Update:- Also my Arduino board is not dead since it worked when connected to other pc but not working with my windows pc.

What could be the problem? How do I install the port driver back?

Comment: Is it a Genuine Arduino or a cheap Chinese clone?

Comment: cheap Chinese i think

Comment: If you bought it off Amazon or eBay then it will be. Chances are it's dead. Get a new one.

Comment: got if from souq, yea have to check. or maybe problem in usb cable?

Comment: i think you have unsigned drivers see https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=205837.0

Comment: "dim light glowing" says "dead board" to me.  Probably CH340G. Probably breathed on it wrong.

Comment: I changed my pc setting to allow unsigned driver but still not working. Board is not dead since it worked when connected to other pc.

Comment: but then, the power LED is lit?

Comment: its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

I connected the arduino with my motor shield on top of it which stopped the power supply from pc. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Windows will disable a given USB port if it think's the attached device is malfunctioning.  Try using a different USB port on your PC.  If that does't work try
rebooting your PC.

Comment: I think that's the problem. I connected the Arduino to another PC and it worked so problem is not in the board but in my pc driver. Even using different usb port didn't work. How do I reboot the pc exactly?

Answer (score 0):

No LED = no power being supplied. That would imply a bad port, a bad cable, or a damaged board (open circuit due to a damaged trace or part).

A brief LED can mean the board was drawing too much current and the computer shut down that port to protect itself. That would imply a damaged board (short circuit due to burned out part, bad wiring if you have any on the board, or something conductive touching your board where it shouldn't (anywhere!).

Try substituting ports, cables, & Arduinos - one thing at a time - until something changes to give you a clue to what component is faulty.

You might also have a driver problem, but a good board/cable/port should power up anyway.

Comment: Problem is in driver. I connected the Arduino board to another PC and it started working but not working in my pc.